# Using a custom field value as current users name

Tags: users, content

I'd like to use conditional logic to show a part of the single post page to a specific user. 
However the problem is Im pulling that username in from a custom field.

Below is what I have so far.

```
    <?php if ( $current_user->user_login =='the_field("my_field")') { ?>

<h1>Welcome <?php echo $current_user->user_firstname ?></h1>

<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php } else { ?>

<?php the_excerpt(); ?>

<div class="apply">APPLY FOR THIS</div>

<?php } ?>
```

And this is not working. However if i use the username as normal for example:

```
<?php if ( $current_user->user_login =='jacksonsmith') { ?>
```

Then this works fine.

So, I'm wondering how can I use the value of a custom field within an if statement as user login name value?

I am a newbie forgive my ignorance!!

Thanks

Comment: `the_field` is a ACF function, right? *Don't* put the function in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're testing for a string, as you're wrapping `the_field("my_field")` in single quotes. So, you want to remove these quotes. Next, `the_field("my_field")` outputs a field, it doesn't return it. You should try `get_field` instead of `the_field`.